# Drupal 6 APC with domain access module not working for (sub-)domains

Tags: 6, domain-access, caching

I've recently enabled APC in my environment and using it with [cache backport](http://drupal.org/project/cache_backport) and [APC beta 7.x-1.0beta3](http://drupal.org/project/apc) which is a backported version for D6 modules respectively in site running drupal 6.22 which uses [domain access module]. The APC is being put to good use as I'm able to observe better page load times on subsequent requests and good number of hits in the System Entries of caching. However the other sites do not show any such improvement and apparently are not cached altogether, I have my domain settings included at the end of the settings.php and the cache related at the beginning, as using the domain access include in front like [this suggestion](http://drupal.org/node/1237180) only seemed to mess up the APC.

```
$thishost = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$site_arr = explode('.', $thishost);
$sitename = $site_arr[1] . '_';
$conf['cache_inc'] = 'sites/all/modules/cache_backport/cache.inc';
$conf['cache_backends'][] = 'sites/all/modules/apc/drupal_apc_cache.inc';
$conf['session_inc'] = 'sites/all/modules/cache_backport/session.inc';    
$conf['cache_prefix'] = $sitename;   
$conf['page_cache_without_database'] = TRUE;
$conf['page_cache_invoke_hooks'] = FALSE;    
$conf['cache_default_class'] = 'DrupalAPCCache';
$conf['cache_class_cache'] = 'DrupalAPCCache';
$conf['cache_class_cache_block'] = 'DrupalAPCCache';
$conf['cache_class_cache_bootstrap'] = 'DrupalAPCCache';
$conf['cache_class_cache_content'] = 'DrupalAPCCache';
$conf['cache_class_cache_filter'] = 'DrupalAPCCache';
$conf['cache_class_cache_form'] = 'DrupalAPCCache';
$conf['cache_class_cache_menu'] = 'DrupalAPCCache';
$conf['cache_class_cache_page'] = 'DrupalAPCCache';
$conf['cache_class_cache_pathdst'] = 'DrupalAPCCache';
$conf['cache_class_cache_pathsrc'] = 'DrupalAPCCache';
$conf['cache_class_cache_session'] = 'DrupalAPCCache';
$conf['cache_class_cache_session_user'] = 'DrupalAPCCache';
$conf['cache_class_cache_update'] = 'DrupalAPCCache';
$conf['cache_class_cache_users'] = 'DrupalAPCCache';
$conf['cache_class_cache_views'] = 'DrupalAPCCache';
$conf['cache_class_cache_views_data'] = 'DrupalAPCCache';
.
.
.
/** domain access include file **/
include './sites/all/modules/domain/settings.inc';
```

My knowledge and hands-on with APC is quite limited and I'm uncertain how to proceed further into this... Any insight/suggestions on this would be appreciated.